# Spark: How to transform a Seq of RDD into a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, seq, rdd, flatmap

I'm just starting in Spark & Scala

I have a directory with multiple files in it
I successfully load them using

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(directory)
```

Now I want to go one level up. I actually have a directory that contains sub directories that contain files. My goal is to get an `RDD[(String,String)]` so I can move forward, where the `RDD` represents name and content of the file.

I tried the following:

```
val listOfFolders = getListOfSubDirectories(rootFolder)
val input = listOfFolders.map(directory => sc.wholeTextFiles(directory))
```

but I got a `Seq[RDD[(String,String)]]`
How do I transform this `Seq` into an `RDD[(String,String)]` ?

Or maybe I'm not doing things right and I should try a different approach?

**Edit**: added code

```
// HADOOP VERSION
val rootFolderHDFS = "hdfs://****/"
val hdfsURI = "hdfs://****/**/"

// returns a list of folders (currently about 800)
val listOfFoldersHDFS = ListDirectoryContents.list(hdfsURI,rootFolderHDFS)
val inputHDFS = listOfFoldersHDFS.map(directory => sc.wholeTextFiles(directory))
// RDD[(String,String)]
//    val inputHDFS2 = inputHDFS.reduceRight((rdd1,rdd2) => rdd2 ++ rdd1)
val init = sc.parallelize(Array[(String, String)]())
val inputHDFS2 = inputHDFS.foldRight(init)((rdd1,rdd2) => rdd2 ++ rdd1)

// returns org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
println(inputHDFS2.count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading each directory into a separate RDD, can you just use a path wild card to load all directories into a single RDD?

Given the following directory tree...

```
$ tree test/spark/so
test/spark/so
├── a
│   ├── text1.txt
│   └── text2.txt
└── b
    ├── text1.txt
    └── text2.txt
```

Create the RDD with a wildcard for the directory.

```
scala> val rdd =  sc.wholeTextFiles("test/spark/so/*/*")
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = test/spark/so/*/ WholeTextFileRDD[16] at wholeTextFiles at <console>:37
```

Count is 4 as you would expect.

```
scala> rdd.count
res9: Long = 4

scala> rdd.collect
res10: Array[(String, String)] =
Array((test/spark/so/a/text1.txt,a1
a2
a3), (test/spark/so/a/text2.txt,a3
a4
a5), (test/spark/so/b/text1.txt,b1
b2
b3), (test/spark/so/b/text2.txt,b3
b4
b5))
```

Comment: I'm finding this solution to be incredibly slow.  It seems to be single-threaded or something.  I can load the same data much faster creating a list of RDD's one per directory, though then I have the problems of stack overflows when unioning them.

Comment: @Brian - I can't see why it would be slower without seeing your implementation and what you're trying to do.  Make a new post and reference this one maybe?

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce on the `Seq` like this (concatenating the `RDD`s with `++`):

```
val reduced: RDD[(String, String)] = input.reduce((left, right) => left ++ right)
```

A few more details why can we apply [reduce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@reduce[A1%3E:A](op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1) here:

- `++` is associative - it does not matter you rdda ++ (rddb ++ rddc) or (rdda ++ rddb) ++ rddc
- assumed the `Seq` is nonempty (otherwise `fold` would be a better choice, it would require an empty `RDD[(String, String)]` as the initial accumulator).

Depending on the exact type of `Seq`, you might get a stackoverflow, so be careful and test with a larger collection, though for the standard library I think it is safe.

Comment: hi! I was using union just before your answer, and got a StackOverflow error... now I'm using ++ and I still get one... what's wrong? org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Hmm. In that case try `reduceRight`/`foldRight`. It might avoid that. (Which version of Scala do you use?)

Comment: I use 2.10.4. Regarding foldRight, how would you write the function? (i need to start with an element, but I don't know how to create an emptyRDD)

Comment: You can use `reduceRight` if you know that will never be empty. For `foldRight`: `val init = sc.parallelize(Array[(String, String)]())`, where `sc` is a `SparkContext`. (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

Comment: Can you tell what is the exact type of the returned `Seq`?

Comment: I updated my post with the code. I'd be tempted to say Seq[RDD[(String,String)]] but I don't want to be mistaken

Comment: I see you managed to solve the other way. Anyway, I was asking about the `getClass` of the `Seq` you got. It seems I remembered wrong and the *Right version stackoverflow for `List`s and the *Left do not. So the non-stackoverflowing alternative might be `reduceLeft` or `foldLeft` if it also uses `scala.collection.immutable.::` (aka non-empty `List`).

Comment: A reduceRight can be more likely to stackoverflow for long lists in Scala, but that's probably not what's happening here.  Stack overflows can happen when unioning lots of RDD's because the RDD's maintain their full lineage.  To shorten the stack, need to periodically .cache() the result and let the intermediate RDD's go out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `union` provided by spark context

```
val rdds: Seq[RDD[Int]] = (1 to 100).map(i => sc.parallelize(Seq(i)))
val rdd_union: RDD[Int] = sc.union(rdds)
```